# Correct usage of the verb liaise

Tags: grammar

Is "liaised" the past tense of liaise?  If so, is this correct or common usage?

Answer (score 4):

*Liaison* is a noun and cannot have a past tense. But yes, *liaised* is the past tense of the verb *to liaise*.

Comment: Just adding re: "is this . . . common usage?" that "to liaise" is not common in AmE compared to "liaison". My dictionary says "Chiefly British" so maybe more common in the UK.

Comment: @joseph_morris  I didn't know that, thanks. In BrE  'to liaise' is commonly used in business/work situations whereas 'liaison' is more social/sexual, especially of an illicit affair. Is that the same in AmE too?

Comment: I think if you say 'they were in a liaison' it implies sexuality. But if you said 'Ben was in liaison with Martha' it would be taken to be a business relationship.

Comment: @WS2 I think I'd be more likely to say 'Ben was liaising with Martha', but both would be acceptable.

Comment: @Mynamite, the literal denotations are the same, but the predominate usage is of the probably-illicit-affair variety. Perhaps, being more puritanical over here, people want to avoid inadvertently giving the impression that they are having an affair with a business contact. Or it was an effect of the movie "Dangerous Liaisons." I dunno.